# Fancybox inline popup on mobile not moving with page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, fancybox

I am working on this website: 
http://www.fairfaxandroberts.com.au/

And I am using fancybox for inline popup:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

When you visit the site you can see the popup that is shown down below the instagram feed when you scroll.

On desktop and larger version it is working well, but on mobile versions the popup is shown when you scroll below insta feed, but it stays on the position where it is shown, it doesn't move with the page scroll behind.

The jQuery code I use to display Fancybox is this:

```
                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
                        var insta_feed_top = $("#slide-55").offset().top;
                        if (y > insta_feed_top) {
                        $(window).off('scroll');
                        $(".fancybox_newsletter")
                            .fancybox({
                                helpers: {
                                    overlay: {
                                      locked: false
                                     }
                                 }
                                }).trigger('click');                              
                        }

                    });
```

What can be the issue guys? I tried a lot, saw the documentation on the site, but nothing works.

Comment: Note: text on your image overlays is too small, not accessible :/

Comment: It's working fine for me both on Desktop and iPhone 6 (chrome mobile emulator - developer tools). + You have errors in your console, check them out.

Comment: I checked on other mobiles like Samsung Galaxy S4 , LG Nexus 4, Sony SmarthPhone and it is fixed on the position where it is shown and not moving with the page scroll...

Comment: Thanks @odedta I will talk with the designer

Comment: Since this is out-of-the-box plugin and we know it works well on mobiles, make sure your website's code is validated and has no errors first, like I said, I tested it and it seems fine to me. Good luck!

Comment: I will fix the errors but I don't think that errors stops the popup from moving with the page scroll, the script is loading and the popup is shown, but why it is not moving is my question, so can you please help me anyway?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem so I can't help you like this :/
I have just checked that again on my Nexus 5 and it works perfect! you should really make sure your system is good before testing :P

Answer (score 0):

[SOLUTION]

Guys after debugging on the mobile, I found that the position was changing on absolute for mobile devices. I just changed the position to be fixed, added some top and left margin and everything looks perfect.

Thanks again.